# Selection algorithm elements within a LinkedList. Java/Android

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I have a LinkedList populated with 500,000 or more of my items. These objects have within two coordinates (x, y) set randomly. Then I have a variable of type Double (radius) that contains a value. The algorithm should give me back a LinkedList containing only objects (selected from 500,000), which are within the range set in the variable. Obviously, the algorithm will need to know what are my coordinates that correspond to the middle of the beam, is then instantiated in part an object that corresponds to myself.

Can someone help me make this algorithm in the form of code java / Android?
Thanks !!

This is my algorithm, but with 500000 elements takes too long:

```
            double radius = 0;
            String text = search_distance.getText().toString();
            if (text.equals("")) {
                ArrayAdapter<Users> adapter = new MyUsersAdapter();
                elenco.setAdapter(adapter);
            } else {
                try {
                    radius = Double.parseDouble(text);
                } catch(NumberFormatException e){
                    Log.e("DEBUG", "Errore: " + e);
                }
            if(!Double.isNaN(radius) && radius > 0) {
                List<Users> listaTemporanea = new LinkedList<Users>();
                for(int i = 0; i < utenti.size(); i++){
                    if(utenti.get(i).getX() < radius && utenti.get(i).getY() < radius) {
                        if(getDistance(utenti.get(i), io) < radius) {
                            listaTemporanea.add(utenti.get(i));
                        }
                    }
                }`
```

Comment: Do you have multiple queries on the same list of Users or is the query ran only once? And what do you mean by too long? How much do you need to improve it?

Comment: And what is the type of `utenti`? Is it an `ArrayList` or a `LinkedList`?

Comment: Research is done each time the beam is changed. My algorithm takes too long to find inside 500000 elements those that fall within the range. wondering if there is some additional control, or a better way to make it much faster. utenti = linkedlist

Comment: Is `utenti` a `LinkedList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LinkedList::get` method has `O(n)` time complexity. That's why the total time complexity of your algorithm is `O(n^2)`(`get` method is called `n` times). It is too slow for `n = 500,000`. There are two ways to fix it:
1. Use access through an iterator(explicitly or implicitly) instead of the `get` method:

```
for (Users curUsers : utenti) {
    // loop body
}
```

2. Use an `ArrayList` instead of a `LinkedList`.

Both of this approaches have `O(n)` time complexity. It should be pretty fast for `n = 500,000`.